# Android 4.1 stock browser: Can't open links in new tab

Tags: android, html, angularjs, android-browser

I am having an issue opening links in a new tab, specifically a link to google maps with location data. It opens in a new tab fine on iOS 6/7, and Chrome Browsers.

Here is the tags I am using:

```
<a class="location" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{ eventDetails.location.latitude }},{{ eventDetails.location.longitude }}" target="_blank">View on map</a>
```

The templates are from AngularJS. I thought `_blank` would be enough to get this browser to pop into a new tab, however the page is loading in the same window.

The device is on a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.1 installed. The user agent string says `AppleWebKit/534.30 Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`

Comment: Neil, @abdulbasit what's your doctype?

Comment: @Neil, <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

You should being using `ng-href` instead of href whenever you use data binding in the url. The browser is likely making a link to your original url. If you use ng-href it will only make the link once your url is properly rendered by angular. See the docs for ng-href [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)